# JApplet NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I'm writing an Japplet on Eclipse, and from a moment to another, it stopped to work on the html page.

Here are the errors:

```
  Exception in thread "thread applet-main.MapGenerator.class-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
at main.Floor.parse(Floor.java:39)
at main.MapGenerator.loadParameters(MapGenerator.java:64)
at main.MapGenerator.start(MapGenerator.java:28)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1698)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:250)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:180)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 5 more
```

And here it is also the server request:

```
  "GET /static/java/MapGenerator.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 68177
  "GET /static/java/com/google/gson/Gson.class HTTP/1.1" 404 1697
```

The point is that it tries to find the Gson library inside the server instead of its package... I don't know how to solve the problem.

If you need something, ask freely.

**EDIT**

I have imported the Gson's library inside my project in eclipse. Actually I don't know why the applet tries to load it from the server... On Eclipse it runs withouth any problem.

**EDIT**

I have copied physically the libraries inside the eclipse project... and it still try to get them from the server... I don't know what else do...

Comment: *"..it stopped to work on the html page."*  What is the URL of that page?

Comment: I don't think it can be useful... but here it is:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/buildings/generate/new_building=45

Comment: Make it available on the net & I'll look into it.

Comment: Sorry but no, it will take too much work to set only this page "outside", it's a part of a complex wizard in six other pages...
But thank you for the offer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st thing you did not add [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library in your classpath and second your request(`GET /static/java/com/google/gson/Gson.class HTTP/1.1`) is wrong.

If you have gson jar under `/static/java` like `MapGenerator.jar`, you could make request for gson jar same as you did for `MapGenerator.jar`. But you can not make request to get class from that jar.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently nobody told me that I cannot insert a Jar inside another Jar, and hope that all works well.

So I put my JAR libraries in the same folder of the applet, and I load the applet this way:

```
    <applet name="mapGenerator"
            id="mapGenerator"  
            code="main.MapGenerator.class"
            archive="{{STATIC_URL}}java/MapGenerator.jar, 
                            {{STATIC_URL}}java/gson-2.2.2.jar,
                            {{STATIC_URL}}java/plugin.jar"
                     >
                    <param name=id value="{{building.id}}">
                    <param name=piani value='{{floors}}'>  
            MAYSCRIPT
    </applet>
```